# Usage of 'mut' keyword in Rust

Tags: rust

I have a question on 'mut' usage in Rust Language.

```
use std::io;

fn main() {
    println!("Guess the number!");

    println!("Please input your guess.");

    let mut guess = String::new();

    io::stdin()
        .read_line(&mut guess)
        .expect("Failed to read line");

    println!("You guessed: {}", guess);
}
```

When the variable guess is already declared as 'mut' why we should again qualify it with 'mut' in the function call to read_line()?

Comment: https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch04-02-references-and-borrowing.html

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/75a0lc/if_a_functions_parameter_is_mut_why_do_i_have_to/

Comment: TLDR; code is read much more often than it is written. The `&mut` in the call is here to make it clear to people reading the code that this specific instruction may change the value.

Answer (score 3):

`.read_line` expects a mutable reference, so you must create `&mut` of the variable.

Please note that `let mut guess = String::new();` creates a variable which *owns* the String. `.readline` wants to change the contents of the string without getting ownership. That way you will still be able to use `guess` after the function call. If you would pass `guess` directly to the function, you wouldn't be able to do anything with it afterwards. Thus you need to create a mutable reference first, that you can pass to `.readline`.